# Return strange value when extract all values from a list of dicts in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Now I have a list of dicts like this:

```
test_dict = [{'Id': 3, 'Name': 'Marcus', 'Email': 'mar@gmail.com'}, {'Id': 4, 'Name': 'Sally', 'Email': 'sally@gmail.com'}]
```

What I want to do is to first convert into a tuple and write the record into table in database.
The outcome that I want to achieve is like:

```
[(3, 'Marcus', 'mar@gmail.com'), (4,'Sally', 'sally@gmail.com')]
```

I used the following code to extract the values:

```
list_test = []

for x in test_dict:
    data = x.values()
    list_test.append(data)

print(list_test)
```

And I got the following:

```
[dict_values([3, 'Marcus', 'mar@gmail.com']), dict_values([4, 'Sally', 'sally@gmail.com'])]
```

Before I though it might be an default value and I tried to get the element e.g 3 in this case with `print(list_test[0][1])`, it returns error:

```
TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable
```

Why this happens? And if I want to achieve the aim, how should I write?
Thanks!

Comment: You want `tuples = [tuple(d.values()) for d in test_dict]`, where `tuples` will be a list of tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests, you cannot index `dict_values`.

You can however cast to [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) using a list comprehension:

```
>>> list_test = [tuple(x.values()) for x in test_dict]
>>> list_test
[(3, 'Marcus', 'mar@gmail.com'), (4, 'Sally', 'sally@gmail.com')]
>>> list_test[0][1]
'Marcus'
```

Or using your original code:

```py
list_test = []

for x in test_dict:
    data = tuple(x.values())
    list_test.append(data)

print(list_test)
# [(3, 'Marcus', 'mar@gmail.com'), (4, 'Sally', 'sally@gmail.com')]

print(list_test[0][1])
# 'Marcus'
```

You could also be explicit and fetch the keys directly:

```py
>>> [(x['Id'], x['Name'], x['Email']) for x in test_dict]
[(3, 'Marcus', 'mar@gmail.com'), (4, 'Sally', 'sally@gmail.com')]
```

Comment: will `tuple(x.values())` maintain the order the op wants?

Comment: @VishalSingh Yes, python 3.6+ preserves dictionary insertion order, and since `values()` is just a view of the dictionary values, nothing is changed when you cast `tuple`. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) for reference.

Comment: @RoadRunner Thanks and it works!
But actually why the code that I wrote returned the strange value?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error, because in the list_test, you are having list of dictionary objects. So for doing the indexing, first you need to select the dictionary objects, and then you need to convert it to a list, and then apply indexing:

```html
list(list_test[0])[0]
```

Comment: Thank you! So that means, the error that I made was because I was extracting the index from the dicts itself, instead of the values inside the dicts?

Comment: Yes, by first indexing, so list_test[0] we are getting dictionary objects, then for extracting the values out of this object using indexing, u need to convert it to a list, and then u r able to extract values by another indexing: list(list_test[0])[0]